Why does GCC have different behaviour of compiled code which should do the same?
I observed some unclear behaviour in a C program compiled with GCC. Could anyone explain why there is a difference in the following code?
1a) The condition -1.30000007F >= ((float)-13 * 0.1F) results in false.
1b) If I split up the condition into a variable assignment of the right side and compare it afterwards it results in true
float tmp_var = (float)-13 * 0.1F; // tmp_var = -1.30000007
-1.30000007F >= tmp_var // true

This happens with gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 12.2.0.
It is not happening with Greenhills compiler.

Additionally I saw as well
2a) (float)20999999 * 0.000001F < (float)21 is true
2b) while the following results in false
float tmp_var = (float)20999999 * 0.000001F; // 21.0
tmp_var < (float)21 // false

Based on the IEE-754 Floating Point Converter 20999999 is stored as 21000000.0 in float.

Even evaluating the expressions in the debugger (gdb) never result in the Xa) variants.

The C standard allows implementations to evaluate float expressions using double precision (or other precision greater than float), similarly to the way integer expressions are evaluated with at least int arithmetic even if they have all char operands. Casts and assignments are required to “discard” the excess precision, which would explain why your tmp_var changes the result. However, simple testing with GCC 12.2.0 for MinGW-W64 on Compiler Explorer does not reproduce this. You should provide a [mre].

@Maro please report the result of printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);   printf("%a\n", tmp_var);   printf("%a\n", (float)-13 * 0.1F);   printf("%a\n", -1.30000007f);  printf("%a\n", 0.1F); .  Your results will lead to a good answer.

also show your compiler options

@Maro I tried to make the same thing you had but I couldn't, I tested using the same gcc version you had, but I got equal results, I disabled optimization and also the same idea. I could.t get what you have.

@Maro if you want to debug, you can do something like this gcc -O0 -S -o test1.s test.c, and then do it again using green hills ghs-cmp -S -o test2.s test.c, now you will get 2 assembly codes from each compiler, compare them to tell the difference.

@Maro in assembly you should find something like this:
movss .LC0(%rip), %xmm0 # Load 1.30000007F into %xmm0
movss .LC1(%rip), %xmm1 # Load -13 * 0.1F into %xmm1
comiss %xmm1, %xmm0 # Compare 1.30000007F with -13 * 0.1F

Thanks all for your comments! Please find below the answers, but first the
Not a Solution, but points to consider.
The issue depends on the processor. Legacy x86 processors perform single precision values using double extended precision. This causes differences in the evaluation. Using the GCC compiler option -ffloat-store prevents such indeterministic behavior.
For more modern x86 processors which support SSE2 the opiton -mfpmath=sse -msse2 works as well. These flag should be used whenever predictable numerical results are required.

@Eric I assume the Compiler Explorer is not running on a x86 processor, that's why there is different behaviour. I'm sorry not providing a suitable minimal example.
@chux (when using -mfpmath=sse -msse2 FLT_EVAL_METHOD is 0, with -ffloat-store it is 2 as below default) I assume that having everything defined in one function/file will not work. The original code receives the left hand side values from python calling the function from a library.
2
-0x1.4ccccep+0
-0x1.4ccccep+0
-0x1.4ccccep+0
0x1.99999ap-4

@M.M other compiler options: -g

Note that @notifications only work in comments, not in answers.

That is hardly a solution since none of that is guaranteed, it is all implementation dependent.  The real take home is that you cannot safely compare calculated binary floating point values for equality with a decimal literal constant and expect precise results.  The decimal literal constants are converted to a binary floating point and may not be precisely represented.  Moreover float values converted to decimal are precise to only 6 significant digits.  Round-trip conversions decimal to float to decimal can further introduce errors.

@Clifford Thanks for the advice. Actually in the formula the values are coming from different signals. The only literal constant is 0.1F: signal >= (float)int_treshold_10th * 0.1F I just wrote down the values I was observing. I was not aware that this makes the difference.
